# Symfony 4.2 on shared hosting - no access to resources - images, css and js

Tags: symfony

I have one problem.
Until recently I used 4.1 and there was no such problem, now 4.2 I have the following problem.

I running 4.2 on shared hosting, but the includes css files, photos and js files are not loading. They are in a public folder. When trying to access such a file, the error is No route found for "GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css". I tried to add base_path in framework.yaml but this is not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does anything work?  Does public/index.php get served?  I assume you have double checked that public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css exists?

Comment: Everything else works. Controllers and methods are being loaded, resources placed in the public directory do not.

Comment: Hey, the problem is fine. I do not know how it happened. I just wiped the folder in the public directory and got it back and everything went. I do not know what this problem is, I cleaned the cache several times. Everything is good now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it happened. I just wiped the folder in the public directory and got it back and everything went. I do not know what this problem is, I cleaned the cache several times. Everything is good now.